# Create custom extension through Graph API with Client Credentials auth

Tags: azure, active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-graph-api

I have a .NET Web API that I am using to do some interaction with Microsoft Graph and Azure AD. However, when I attempt to create an extension on the user, it comes back with Access Denied.

I know it is possible from the documentation [here](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/beta/api/opentypeextension_post_opentypeextension) however, it doesnt seem to work for me.

For the API, I am using client credentials. So my web app authenticates to the API using user credentials, and then from the API to the graph it uses the client.

My app on Azure AD has the Application Permission `Read and Write Directory Data` set to true as it states it needs to be in the documentation for a user extension.

I know my token is valid as I can retrieve data with it.

Here is my code for retrieving it:

```
    private const string _createApprovalUrl = "https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/users/{0}/extensions";
    public static async Task<bool> CreateApprovalSystemSchema(string userId)
    {
        using(var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            using(var req = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, _createApprovalUrl))
            {
                var token = await GetToken();
                req.Headers.Add("Authorization", string.Format("Bearer {0}", token));
                req.Headers.TryAddWithoutValidation("Content-Type", "application/json");
                var requestContent = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new { extensionName = "<name>", id = "<id>", approvalLimit = "0" });
                req.Content = new StringContent(requestContent, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

                using(var response = await client.SendAsync(req))
                {
                    var content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                    ApprovalSystemSchema schema = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ApprovalSystemSchema>(content);
                    if(schema.Id == null)
                    {
                        return false;
                    }
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Is there anyone who may have a workaround on this, or information as to when this will be doable?

Thanks,

Comment: We'll investigate and get back to you.  Thanks for reporting this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We took a look and it looks like you have a bug/line of code missing.  You appear to be making this **exact** request:

```
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/users/{0}/extensions
```

Looks like you are missing the code to replace the `{0}` with an actual user id.  Please make the fix and let us know if you are now able to create an extension on the user.